# JQuery Animate works only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The below code works in [http://jsfiddle.net/6LbFB](http://jsfiddle.net/6LbFB/) but failing while I run in my localhost, it only moves to 1 position only, any guess.

```
                $('.position').click(function () {
                if ($('#preview-bio').css('display') == 'none')
                    $('#preview-bio').show();
                $('#preview-desc').text($('#user-bio').val());
                if ($(this).prop('id') == 'topleft') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: 0 }, "slow")
                    .animate({ top: 0 }, "slow");
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'bottomleft') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: 0 }, "slow")
                    .animate({ bottom: 0 }, "slow");
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'topright') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ right: 0 }, "slow")
                    .animate({ top: 0 }, "slow");
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'bottomright') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ right: 0 }, "slow")
                    .animate({ bottom: 0 }, "slow");
                }
                if ($('#fixed').prop('checked') == 'checked') {
                    $('#preview-bio').prop('position', 'fixed');
                }
               // $('#preview-desc').fitText();
            });
```

**UPDATE 7:27-1358**

I looked various other posts, the issue seems to be with subsequent animate positions (left/right/top/bottom) that needs to be either incremental or decremental by ratio. Is what my guess is

**UPDATE 7:27-1508**

This maybe helpful for someone, I fixed the issue, animate works with relative positions hence it could not move from (top:0, left:0) to (bottom:0,left:0) instead something like (top:200, left:0) has moved from top to bottom, actually there are other posts (in stackoverflow) on these issue helped me figure out this issue. Can check at http://jsfiddle.net/6LbFB/3/

The new code looks like as below

```
              $('.position').click(function () {
                if ($('#preview-bio').css('display') == 'none')
                    $('#preview-bio').show();
                $('#preview-desc').text($('#user-bio').val());
                if ($(this).prop('id') == 'topleft') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: '0' }).animate({top:'0'});
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'bottomleft') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: '0' }).animate({ top: '300' });
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'topright') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: '410' }, "slow")
                    .animate({ top: 0 }, "slow");
                }
                else if ($(this).prop('id') == 'bottomright') {
                    $('#preview-bio').animate({ left: '410' }, "slow")
                    .animate({ top: '300' }, "slow");
                }
                if ($('#fixed').prop('checked') == 'checked') {
                    $('#preview-bio').prop('position', 'fixed');
                }
                //$('#preview-desc').fitText();
            });
```

Comment: Please post the full code you're using. Most likely either your path to jQuery is wrong, or your code isn't being executed after the DOM is ready.

Comment: @j08691 I checked in console there are no issues with jQuery 1.11.1 I am loading in DOM, the same version tested in JSFiddle which is working, the code exist in http://jsfiddle.net/6LbFB/1/

Comment: So... you don't want to post your full example? OK well then good luck with that.

Comment: its the same html code as here http://jsfiddle.net/6LbFB/1/

Comment: Obviously it's not the same, otherwise it'd work ;)